# Gradle project sync failed for android support multidex library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to add Multidex library to my project. I added following as dependency in my 'app/build.gradle' -

```
complie 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

when i try to sync i can see following error

```
Error:Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

i have Android Support Repository installed.

[image: SDK Manager snapshot]

Can someone help me? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add multiDexEnabled = true in your build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  ...
}
```

add this to manifest file

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

and your Activity class

```
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
     }
```

Comment: I tried to create new project and it is working fine without 'multiDexEnabled=true'. or other suggestions. But thanks for your reply @Raju, it encouraged me to try new version.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that you are editing the correct build.gradle file. You will get this error when editing android/build.gradle instead of android/app/build.gradle.