# Android studio - Android Support Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to add dependency for multidex, but I have issue with Android Support Repository inside my Android Studio project.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

When i try to compile the project the following error occurs:

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>   Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
>   Open Android SDK Manager

But the **Android Support Repository** is installed.

[image: SDK Manager window]

So what should be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle project sync failed for android support multidex library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839795/gradle-project-sync-failed-for-android-support-multidex-library)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `multiDexEnabled true` in your build.gradle. It will be like this:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
      multiDexEnabled true
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```